# Common Lisp: defpackage and exporting symbols that are created programmaticaly

Tags: common-lisp, package

how would you / should you export symbols from a package, when you have not yet created them at the time of calling the defpackage macro?

```
(defpackage :package-a
  (:use :cl)
  (:export :fruit-type :animal-type :orange :apple :peach :cat :dog))

(deftype fruit-type () '(member ORANGE APPLE PEACH))
(deftype animal-type () '(member CAT DOG))

(defparameter *other-symbol-names*
  '("A1" "A2" "B1" "B2")) ;imagine a longer list here
                          ;with names generated by a function

(defparameter *other-symbols*
  (mapcar #'(lambda (sym-name)
          (import (make-symbol sym-name))
          (find-symbol sym-name))
      *other-symbol-names*))

(mapcar #'export *other-symbols*)

(setf A1 32 A2 33 B1 34 B2 35)
```

also there is another package

```
(defpackage :package-b
  (:use :cl :package-a))
(in-package :package-b)
(format nil "~a ~a ~a ~a" |A1| |A2| |B1| |B2|)
```

I have read in "The Complete Idiot’s Guide to Common Lisp Packages" that
"Now that you’ve learned all about the myriad functions and macros that can be
used to manipulate packages you shouldn’t really be using any of them. Instead,
all of the functionality of IMPORT, EXPORT, SHADOW, etc. is all rolled up in a
single macro called DEFPACKAGE, which is what you should use for real (non-
prototype) code."

Is there a code smell in my above code? Also, how would you export the other symbols (cat dog animal-type, etc. -- there are many of them) to avoid duplication?

Comment: What "smells" is that you need to export so many dynamically-created symbols in the first place. What is the higher level intent?

Comment: I am sure this could be done in fifty other ways, but I am new to Common Lisp and I ended up with an organization where those symbols' definitions are in a different package than where I am using them and I need to export them. Perhaps I did not phrase my question correctly, my symbols are not dynamically generated, the function that generates them fills the *other-symbol-names* only one time (inside defparameter *other-symbol-names*) and they do not change after that. It is just that they are many symbols, about one hundred.

Comment: The names you gave in the example looked like you might be using lots of numbered symbols, which should probably be just a couple of arrays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to say much without knowing more about your intent and requirements, but in many situations it would be better to have one or more hash tables (or similar) which contain your dynamically generated objects, and then export symbol(s) for your hash table(s).

Here's a hand-wavy example of how this can work. If you can edit and add some more information about your requirements and constraints I'll see if I can be more help.

```
(in-package :cl)

(defpackage :package-a
  (:use :cl)
  (:export *objects* put get)
  (:shadow get))

(in-package :package-a)

(defvar *objects* (make-hash-table)
  "Container for dynamically generated objects we want to expose to the
  package's user.")

(defun put (name obj)
  (setf (gethash name *objects*) obj))

(defun get (name &optional default)
  (gethash name *objects* default))

;; Your code can put arbitrary objects into the hash table
(put :foo (lambda () :a-thunk))
(put :bar (lambda () :another))

;; And your users can retrieve them
(in-package :cl-user)
(use-package :package-a)
(funcall (get :foo)) ;; => :a-thunk
```

I used keywords for the names rather than symbols because keywords aren't local to packages (or, more specifically, they're all local to the `keyword` package. If you were to instead use `'foo` and `'bar` you'd be back to needing to export those symbols, or your user would need to use the package designator when refer to them (e.g. `(get 'package-a::foo)`).

You can also use strings as keys, though in that case you would want to create the table with `(make-hash-table :test 'equal)`. The default hash table test is `#'eql`, which doesn't compare strings appropriately. Comparing keywords with `#'eql` is faster than comparing strings with `#'equal` (because keywords are a simple pointer comparison, as opposed to the character-by-character comparison necessary for strings) but the difference is likely insignificant unless you have specific reason to think otherwise.

This approach provides a better interface for your users, because now your have defined entry points, the opportunity for docstrings, defaults, and easier exploration at the REPL.

Comment: thank you for your answer, although I guess it is more complicated than I need.

Comment: You should not use `get`, as that is an exported symbol from the `common-lisp` package (the accessor `get` does lookups in symbol property lists).

Comment: @Svante, you're right insofar as getting into the details would needlessly complicate the topic under discussion, but in general I don't see any reason not to shadow packages from `cl`. The ability to use names appropriate to your program, regardless of what names others have or haven't used, is a big part of the utility provided by things like Common Lisp's package system. `cl:get` is completely absent from many programs; it would be a shame for "get" to be off-limits anyway.

Comment: Yes, but please note CLHS chapter 11.1.2.1.2 on restrictions for conforming programs.  Note that for example in SBCL, you will have to disable or circumvent a package lock to do a `defun get`.  The rationale is quite simple: anyone would find it surprising if a basic function from the spec did not do what it says it does in the spec.

Comment: @Svante, that would only be true without `(:shadow get)` in the `defpackage` form. The result of shadowing the symbol `cl:get` is that it isn't imported into `package-a` at all. So `defun get` isn't redefining `cl:get`, it's simply defining `package-a:get`. Similarly, code consuming `package-a` would `(:shadowing-import-from :package-a get)` in their own `defpackage`. Try it in SBCL: package locks are only triggered if you *don't* shadow `cl:get`.

Comment: @Svante see the [CLHS entry on cl:shadow](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_shadow.html) for some more info. There are no restrictions (that I know of) on shadowing symbols from the `cl` package. FWIW, in part of the examples on that page they shadow `cl:car`.

Comment: Heh, I could have sworn that that `shadow` declaration was not there when I commented (yes, I know how shadowing works).  I still would not recommend it